# FFMpeg estimated execution time

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm using [FFmpegAndroid](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) library in my project to overlay a video.

The ffmpeg process is inside a service and I want to show the user a notification with progress to determine the progress of the process.

I've went through the outputs of the ffmpeg but there's nothing that specify the estimated duration time.
Maybe it's possible to calculate it by other params that shown in the output such as **fps, bitrate or speed** but I have no clue..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such purpose you can use [FFProbe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) with this command:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 example.mp4
```

The output will be in seconds:

[image]

So to show the progress of your video processing, first you use FFProbe to get the video length, then while FFMpeg works on the processing you calculate remaining time from FFMpeg progress output.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, is ffprobe part of the ffmpeg library?

Comment: @Juvi Yes it is.

Comment: So for example, i'm resizing my video, where do i specify the resize command as i do in ffmpeg? i.e: -vf scale=240:360

Comment: First you use ffprobe to get the video length, then while ffmpeg works you calculate remaining time from ffmpeg progress output.

Comment: I'm getting "ffmpeg Unrecognized option 'show_entries'", might be because it's an android lib of ffmpeg?

Comment: it is... "ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 " + screenRecordVideoPath

Comment: @Juvi hmmm... You can still use `ffprobe -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 example.mp4` and it will show you the duration, but with all other data... is that OK ?

Comment: Same issue about unrecognized options.. My guess is that ffprobe isn't supported in the ffmpeg version for android

Comment: @Juvi I think that you do not understand that FFprobe is not a command in FFMpeg, it's another EXE in the same library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146653/discussion-between-juvi-and-koby-douek).

Answer (score 0):

The way to calculate the progress is first to get the video duration:

can be done with ffmpeg and also with android native class such as MediaMetadataRetriever as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394640/get-duration-of-audio-file).

After we get in onProgress callback of ffmpeg execution the time of the video i.e:

```
frame=  171 fps= 27 q=29.0 size=      43kB time=00:00:04.06 bitrate=  87.5kbits/s dup=12 drop=9 speed=0.651x
```

Than we are able to get the progress percent of the excution.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how can I get the time from the ongoing progress?