# Get duration of an audio file - Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to the duration of my audio files by clicking on them through a `ListView`. In this list view I am correctly displaying the names on them and I am able to play them, but I would like to know its duration.

I have looked for different questions in Stackoverflow which actually seem to answer this question but I am not truly able to do it so I will leave here my attempt. I have tried to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394640/get-duration-of-audio-file) but it does not work so I assume that I am falling getting or understanding the `Uri`.

The file is stored at `/raw/`

**JAVA - 1st attempt**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // play desired audio
            Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
            if(soundMap.selectedEncoder != null) {
                //Log.d(TAG,  String.valueOf(soundMap.getX()) + " " + String.valueOf(soundMap.getY()));
                soundMap.selectedEncoder.play(position, audioFiles[position]);

                // Get duration of the audio file
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("/raw/"+fields[position].getName());
                MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                mmr.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
                String durationStr = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                //int audioFileDuration = Integer.parseInt(durationStr);

            }
        }
    });
```

The audios are stored at the `raw` folder. I have also tried to add `.mp3` to the `uri`

**ERROR**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: myapp, PID: 26303
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

**JAVA - 2nd attempt**

```
File audioFile = new File("/raw/"+fields[position].getName()+ ".mp3");
                    mmr.setDataSource(context, Uri.fromFile(audioFile));
                    String time = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                    long timeInMillisec = Long.parseLong(time );
```

**EDIT - 3rd attempt**
In the end I have used `MediaPlayer`

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.andthenturnleft);
                if (afd == null) return;
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                int audioFileDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                /*try {
```

and I get the duration of the file. Nevertheless, first I get the following error:

> E/MediaPlayerNative: Attempt to call getDuration in wrong state:
>   mPlayer=0xf6f4e7a0, mCurrentState=2

I assume that the error is generated because during the first attempt to get the duration the `MediaPlayer` is not ready yet. I would like to stop the code until is ready. Nevertheless, in the end I get `audioFileDuration` with a value of `24` which is not possible because it should return the value in milliseconds and the file is 2seconds long.

**4th attempt**

```
String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path + fields[position].getName() + ".mp3");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                int audioFileDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
```

the problem is this case is that I get  a value of 0 because it does not find the file

> open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

How could I properly get the `path` of the file?

**SOLVED**
I have posted my own solution. I just needed to find a new way to set the path of the file and I finally managed to do it.

Comment: u have probelm in mediametadata retriver

Comment: also i have edited ur code try that...if it doesn't work use my below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I used another way to get the `path` of the file and I was able to solve this error. I copy here the code that I used:

```
 Uri mediaPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.package.name/" + R.raw.audioname);
                mmr.setDataSource(context, mediaPath);
                String duration = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                Log.d(TAG, duration);
                mmr.release();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    implementation 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.14'

            FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever metadataRetriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
                metadataRetriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
                metadataRetriever.setDataSource(url);
        LogMessage.v("1::Duration" + retriever.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
```