# Get video duration from FileDescriptor or ParcelFileDescriptor

Tags: android, cordova, mediastore, mediametadataretriever

I've been using this type of code to get the duration of videos on my Android device:

```
            int dataColumn = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);
            String path = cursor.getString(dataColumn);

            MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            File file = new File(path);
            retriever.setDataSource(context, Uri.fromFile(file));
            boolean hasVideo = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_HAS_VIDEO).equals("yes");
            String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
            int duration = 0;
            if (time != null && hasVideo) {
                duration = (int) Math.ceil(Integer.parseInt(time) / 1000);
            }
```

This was working until I began to target Android 11 (API level 30) in my app. Now the duration is always reported as `0`. I can see that `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA` was [deprecated beginning with Android 10 (API level 29)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#DATA), and `ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor` is the recommended alternative. However, I don't know how to get a video's duration from a `ParcelFileDescriptor` or `FileDescriptor`. I also haven't been able to find resources that demonstrate how to do so. So, how can I do that?

I've also tried other possible solutions, none of which have worked:

- Using `retriever.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath())` instead of `retriever.setDataSource(context, Uri.fromFile(file))`. I saw that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61336282/7987987) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42250183/7987987), so I tried it but it didn't work (the duration is still zero)
- I tried querying the duration field directly from the `MediaStore` but it still didn't work. This was the code I used:

```
                            int vidDurationColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);
                            int duration = (int)cursor.getInt(vidDurationColumn);
```

So yeah, I'm open to any ideas that work. Thanks!